# Symfony2 / Doctrine2 - get sql min,max date values

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, max, min

My problem is when i want to get the max or the min date value between 2013-04-08,2013-04-07 and 2013-04-06, the response is always 2013-04-08 for the min and the max

my script  :

```
$max_date =     $em ->createQuery("SELECT MAX(p.date) FROM TrackingMarqueBundle:PointdeventeOperateursSaisie p")
                        ->getSingleScalarResult();
    $min_date =     $em ->createQuery("SELECT MIN(p.date) FROM TrackingMarqueBundle:PointdeventeOperateursSaisie p")
                        ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Any help please?

Comment: Show us an example of your data

Comment: this is the [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4vJ-uPw9euzNzZPQ3loczRVd2M/edit?usp=sharing) , but it's a simple table

Comment: someone has test this problem ?! i would like to know if the problem is only mine!!

Comment: Your spreadsheet requires invitation, which creates a barrier to helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
$em ->createQuery("SELECT MAX(p.date) max_date,MIN(p.date) min_date FROM TrackingMarqueBundle:PointdeventeOperateursSaisie p")->getArrayResult();
```

I have this code works correctly

```
doctrine/orm                         v2.5.10
```